# can the input voltage to ADC exceed the reference in LPC 2468

Tags: adc

I'm working on lpc 2468 internal ADC .the reference voltage used is 2.5V and the maximum voltage to adc is 3.5 V ,is this acceptable to provide to IC if not is there any other option?

Comment: Is what acceptable? This question is too vague to answer in its present form.

Comment: No, I'm not going to look up what  a LPC2468 is.  Without a datasheet link it is impossible to know what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

You will saturate the ADC at 2.5V and anything past that won't matter. The datasheet indicates that the ADC input can handle input voltages up to \$V_{DDA}\$. It looks to me like you need to look into the programming guide a little deeper, and see where the reference is set. I'll bet there are a couple of bits in the ADC control registers that allow you to select the reference voltage.

Comment: so if a higher voltage like 5V is applied it does not effect the ic??

Comment: Maybe? It depends on what decisions the parts designers made, and I'm not about to go digging for you if you're not even willing to read the datasheet.

Comment: thank you Matt, but im a fresher working on this IC in the design we have requirement that  reference voltage to be 2.5V and the input to the ADC is limited by a clipper circuit with voltage 3.3V and VDD=3.3V so maximum input to the ADC is 3.5V, is this voltage is ok to provide to the IC

Comment: @user19736 - Matt already gave you the answer, but all the info you need is in the datasheet, in the specifications at the end. Read this thoroughly, you need to get into the habit of doing this.